# Catching exceptions from Application.Run()

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this standard code in my project:

```
try {
    myForm = new MyForm();
    Application.Run(myForm);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle all uncaught exceptions
}
```

but, when there is an unhandled exception somewhere in my program, it still shows the "default" exception handler and my `catch` is never hit. I want to handle certain fatal errors as known fatal errors (connection lost, for example).

Comment: @Jehof not quite. I don't want to catch *all* unhandled exceptions. Just some fatal ones, that can occur anywhere in the program. I still want unknown problem to be uncaught (because that gives good debugging info).

Comment: @BartFriederichs all unhandled exceptions are fatal

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I understand. I probably didn't explain it clearly. My app uses a database connection and losing it, doesn't necessarily mean fatal (I could try to reconnect for example), but I want to handle it as fatal right now. Problem is, this exception can be thrown anywhere in my program (basis of this bug is a design fault, but I cannot fix that now), so I want to catch it and make it fatal and close the application with a user friendly message.

Comment: @BartFriederichs you should be able to catch exceptions with ThreadException if you have database operations on main thread. Also you can use UnhandledException event of AppDomain, see linked question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is `AppDomain.UnhandledException`.  Look here for more details:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Also, here is an older - but still excellent - article:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7482/User-Friendly-Exception-Handling

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
 myForm = new MyForm();
 Application.Run(myForm);
 Application.ThreadException +=
         new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
```

and then use this event like this

```
    static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {
          // Your code
      }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          // your code
     }
   }
```

Comment: It works well, but the event must to be calld before the Application.Run(myForm);